# C++: iterating over a list of a generic type

Tags: c++, object, iterator, generics

Yet again I find myself struggling with the C++ syntax.

I'm trying to iterate over a list of generic objects. That is I have objects of a class
`Event<Q>`, crammed into a `std::list<Event<Q> >`.

So I'm trying to get an iterator over the list and intuitively thought that

```
std::list<Event<Q> >::iterator it;
for (it = events.begin(); it != events.end(); it++) { ... }
```

should solve the problem. However, i keep getting these errors:

```
..\calendar.h:48: error: expected `;' before "it"
..\calendar.h:49: error: `it' was not declared in this scope
```

Is there a reason for it being this difficult?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors which you are getting?

Comment: ...and a little bit more code, maybe. How is `events` instantiated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure this should work, but it sounds like you either have one or both of the following in action.

- Have `Q` a template parameter or a type that somehow otherwise depend on it (typedef to it). Put a `typename` before `std::list` then, so that the compiler knows that `::iterator` is a type and can proceed analysis properly (it could be a static value member). Knowing it is a type, the compiler can produce better diagnostics for template definitions, and you are required to tell whether it is a type using `typename`.
- Have `events` a const list. Use `const_iterator` then.

**Update**: The shown compile error surely indicates that the first point is true: `Q` directly or indirectly depends on a template parameter, and you have to put `typename` like so:

```
typename std::list< Event<Q> >::iterator it;
```

The compiler believes you that it is a non-type, and so it requires some operator or semicolon behind `::iterator` (like, a multiplication). Put `typename` to make it know it names a type instead.

**Update**: See the [Template FAQ](http://womble.decadentplace.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html) for similar template issues and solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it. I did:

`typename std::list<Event<S > >::iterator it`

and it magically worked

Comment: Your explanation was very lucid and also solved my problem :) Thanks a lot, Johannes!

Answer (score 0):

in your sample , what is S ?

```
list<Event<S> >::iterator it; // what is S 
for (it = events.begin(); it != events.end(); it++) { ... }
```

can you try putting a native type there ?

```
list<Event<int> >::iterator it; 
for (it = events.begin(); it != events.end(); it++) { ... }
```

or simplify it even more ?

```
list<int>::iterator it; 
for (it = events.begin(); it != events.end(); it++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the std namespace imported? Should the iterator declaration have been:

```
std::list<Event<S> >::iterator it;
```